# usb connection event on linux without udev or libusb

Tags: c, linux, centos, usb

I need to find a way to detect when a usb device is plugged in C on an old embedded Linux (CentOs 4).

`libudev` and `libusb` are not available so I'm a little clueless with my options here. There is `dbus`, however I cannot use `udisks` as the device I need to detect is not a storage device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to write a custom script and register it in `/proc/sys/kernel/hotplug`. When a uevent occurs, the kernel will invoke your script and pass the subsystem (usb in your case) as an argument. Then you will have to match the device (I don't know how to do that, that's probably the most tricky part).

Skeleton for your custom hotplug script that matches the USB subsystem:

```
$ cat my_hotplug.sh 
#!/bin/sh

[ "$1" = usb ] || exit 0
echo "Do something here"
```

Registering your hotplug script as the uevent helper:

```
echo /path/to/my_hotplug.sh > /proc/sys/kernel/hotplug
```

Comment: "man hotplug"  
shows a lot of addition info: inside variable $ACTION is add || remove, $PRODUCT shows the type in hex and $DEVPATH shows the device